# CPU Configuration Issue for 2 Servers (Server 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, asp-classic

I have 2 servers running the exact same Classic ASP code with Access DBs (yes, not ideal, but it is what it is, for now).

1) Xeon 5520 @ 2.27 GHz (6 GB Memory)

2) Xeon E5-2620 @ 2.00 GHz (2 processors, 32 GB Memory)

For most pages the newer E5-2620 processes the pages between 10-15% faster. On pages requiring heavy and/or multiple complicated access stored procedures (queries) the older 5520 does a much better job.

I believe the servers are configured nearly identically. My question: is it possible that the newer, multi-processor server is not as good at handling Classic ASP as the older single processor?

Is there a configuration difference that needs to be in place that I'm missing since I'm shooting for identical implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Classic ASP with Access Databases I can definitely say that the Dual Processor Xeon E5-2620 is not a faster server than the Xeon 5520. Basically, it's the clock speed here - the 2.27 GHz on the older machine processes the ASP code quicker than the 2.00 GHz Dual Core E5-2620.

As an aside I just set up a 3.4 GHz single processor server and it is quicker than both the machines earlier discussed. For Classic ASP processor speed is definitely the determining criteria.